# New-ADGroup with Multiple -OtherAttributes?

Tags: active-directory, powershell, powershell-v3.0

Keep getting "The Paramater is Incorrect". I think I'm following Microsoft's method correctly, but it's not working.

```
New-ADGroup -DisplayName $name -Name $grpName -Server server.org `
  -Path:'DC=server,DC=org' -GroupCategory Distribution `
  -GroupScope DomainLocal -Description $desc `
  -OtherAttributes @{'mail'=$email;'gidNumber'=$gid}}
```

The Microsoft page shows you need to use the semi-colon to separate values, so I'm using

```
  -OtherAttributes @{'mail'=$email;'gidNumber'=$gid}}
```

Is this wrong? Without the `gidNumber` it works fine.

Comment: Ah.. found that my gID was too long.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem with gidNumber in otherAttribues w/ multiple attributes, except that I needed to specify group scope. 
- try specify group scope too
- using a newer version of powershell
- make sure your $gid is valid (not out of range etc.)